# How can I find the date of a process in yyyymmdd format?(UNIX)

Tags: bash, unix

I want to create a file in UNIX in following way:

PID-dato.meminfo

So an example will be like that: 17579-20100216-15:26:31.meminfo

17579 is the process ID, but I dont know how to find the date and time of a process like I have described over.

Comment: What do you mean by "date and time of a process" ?

Comment: I want to create a file with following name processid-thedatewhenprocesswascreated-timewhenprocesswascreated.meminfo. So it will look something like that: 17579-20100216-15:26:31.meminfo, the problem is I dont know how to get the date when the process was created in following format; yyyymmdd(without hyphen) -hh:mm:ss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
echo "$$-`stat --format=%y /proc/$$`.meminfo"
# OR 
x1=$(stat --format=%y /proc/$$ | tr -d '-')
echo "$$-$x1.meminfo"
```

Comment: How can I get the year without hyphen? Because with this one, I get the year with hyphen!

Comment: @JagjitSingh , i made modification

Comment: Thanks that worked. Only problem is that with the time is following something after the dot, like that: 10:32:36.5930....    How do I remove the dot and the content after that?

Comment: @JagjitSingh try this : x2=${x1%.*}